# Nuxt3 and Pinia how to get localstorage items

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, local-storage, vuex, pinia

I'm using `Nuxt3` and `pinia`, and I am pretty new to them both. I am trying to get a token from the localstorage. Now I know that you can't do that because nuxt is `SSR` and it does not have a way to get the client's localstorage. So the localstorage has to be defined after the components got loaded. If I understand that correctly.

So in my website when a user logges in the token is getting successfully stored in the localstorage, but it I can't access it when I reload the page (only if I use the onMounted method).

When I use the onMounted method the I can get the token successfully. But then I have another problem. I want to add a "isAuthenticated" middleware, so when you are already logged in you can't go to the login page again. So I am trying to get the token from the localstorage, and when I do that I am getting either an empty string or "localstorage" is not defined

The login function `<script setup>` (this is working fine) to upload the token in the localStorage

```
import {useTokenStore} from "../store/user/token";
const tokenStore = useTokenStore()

async function login() {
  await useLazyFetch('/api/auth/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      email: `${inpEmail}`,
      password: `${inpPassword}`
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    responseToken = response.data.value
    if (responseToken!=="fout"){
      for (let token in responseToken){
        tokenStore.storeToken(responseToken[token])
      }
    } else {
      errorMsg.value = true
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.data)
  })
}
```

This function (also in `<script setup>` is how I am getting (for now) the token from the localstorage. As you can see I am getting the token after my component is loaded, and restoring it in my state

```
onMounted(() => {
  tokenStore.storeToken(localStorage.getItem('token'))
})
```

This is my my `store/user/token.js`. Here I set the token in the storage

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useTokenStore = defineStore("token", {
    state: () => ({
        userToken: process.server ? '' : localStorage.getItem('token')
    }),
    getters: {
        getUserToken: state => {
            console.log(process.server)
            return state.userToken
        }
    },
    actions: {
        storeToken(token){
            this.userToken = token
            localStorage.setItem('token', this.userToken)
        }
    }
})
```

So after the code above I tried to get in my middleware the `token` from my localstorage
in my `middleware/auth.js`:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) =>{
    const useToken = useTokenStore()
    console.log(useToken.getUserToken + " token")
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
)}
```

So when I run this with the first `console.log` im getting an empty string.
When I try to run it with the second `console.log` I'm getting this error:

```
500
localStorage is not defined

at fn (./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.mjs:151:27)
at Object.callAsync (./node_modules/unctx/dist/index.mjs:49:19)
at Module.callWithNuxt (./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.mjs:153:23)
at ./node_modules/nuxt/dist/pages/runtime/router.mjs:110:50
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So basically how can I get my token, so I can use it in my middleware to check if my token exist?

I know that I just can turn `SSR` off, but I want it on so my website is better for SEO

Comment: I the same exact question/concern. Hope we could get some answers.

Comment: Hey @Hayden, I actually found out that you won't be able to do what I was trying to do. If you store something in your localstorage there is no possible way to get it if you have SSR turned on. So instead of using localstorage you have to use cookies. When u use cookies then you can actually get the token. That's because cookies are automaticlly sent in the headers, and when that happens nuxt knows what to use. Hope that helped you!